# Bindable Layouts > Binding: Property X not found on ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding

I have simple XAML page with code like this:

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}"
                   Text="{Binding Text}"
                   FontAttributes="Italic"
                   FontSize="20"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HeightRequest="105"
                   Margin="25" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

In the view page code behind I have:

```
public partial class DataView
    {
        public DataView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = new ViewModel();
        }
...
}
```

Data is:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Data = new ObservableCollection()<Model> { 
            new Model { Text = "Pink", Color = Color.DeepPink }, 
            new Model { Text = "Crimson", Color = Color.Crimson }, 
            new Model { Text = "Aqua", Color = Color.Aqua }, 
            new Model { Text = "Blue", Color = Color.DeepSkyBlue }, 
            new Model { Text = "BurlyWood", Color = Color.BurlyWood }, };
    }
 
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Data { get; set; }
}
 
public class Model
{
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

However, on compile, I get:

> Binding: Property "Color" not found on "MyComp.ViewModel".

Seems like its searching for Color in ViewModel instead of parent (Data).

I'm using the latest Xamarin.Forms 4.8.0, .NET Standard 2.0 and Visual Studio 2019 16.7.4.

Comment: Try renaming your property with a name other than Color

Comment: Tried with ColorTyp, still the same. Fails at compile time with this error.

Comment: I created a basic sample to test your code, it works fine. Try clean the **obj** and **bin** folders of the project, then rebuild. The code of the 'ViewModel' class should be like below, make sure you reference the correct package. `public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Data = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Model>() {...};
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Data { get; set; }
}`

Comment: Yes, correct package is referenced. I tried with deleting obj and bin, but still the same. I actually simplifed thing here. My page look like: <framework:BaseStateAwareContentPage  x:DataType="ViewModel "
    x:TypeArguments="ViewModel , .../>. Its an example from MS ref app https://github.com/microsoft/TailwindTraders. But, should look the same.

Comment: If I put  [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Skip)] on the page it works.

Comment: The [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Skip)] option will compile the XAML for the class or project when the application is run on the device. Check the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.xaml.xamlcompilationoptions?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: Yes, I know. But its interesting that it compiles with this and works fine. I'm just wondering why my case is not compiling and why binding member is searched in viewmodel instead of BindableLayout.ItemsSource parent.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the xaml code? The above xaml code works fine.

Comment: Nothing is wrong. It just wont compile. If I remove binding line or when i skip compilation of the page it compile and works fine. Looks to me like some bug in Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue according to the description, please post the related code. If you've confirmed it's a potential issue, you could report the issue on github.

Comment: Actually I have something like this: <StackLayout x:Name="expanderLayout" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"><BindableLayout.ItemTemplate> <DataTemplate> <Expander>   <Expander.Header><Grid> <Label BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}"/> </Grid> </Expander.Header> <Expander.ContentTemplate><DataTemplate>...</DataTemplate></Expander.ContentTemplate></Expander></DataTemplate></BindableLayout.ItemTemplate></StackLayout>. And here I get an error for Color. Can you check does this work ?

Comment: I tested the xaml code, it works fine. Check the gif: https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/editor/pd/aa0fp5pwnvkl.gif

Comment: Can you post the code somewhere ? This exact combination I send doesn't work in my project.

Comment: In my example, it is trying to search for Color in ViewModel but not in Data item, which is in itemssource. Do I need to navigate that somehow ?

Comment: I posted the related code, you could refer to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the xaml code, it still works fine.Check the gif: https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/editor/pd/aa0fp5pwnvkl.gif

Here is the related code, you could refer to it.

Page.xaml

```
<StackLayout x:Name="expanderLayout" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander>
                <Expander.Header>
                    <Grid>
                        <Label BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Expander.Header>
                <Expander.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label
                            Text="{Binding Text}"
                            FontAttributes="Italic"
                            FontSize="20"
                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            HeightRequest="105"
                            Margin="25" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Expander.ContentTemplate>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

Page.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Model class and ViewModel class

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Data = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Model>() {
                new Model { Text = "Pink", Color = Color.DeepPink },
            new Model { Text = "Crimson", Color = Color.Crimson },
            new Model { Text = "Aqua", Color = Color.Aqua },
            new Model { Text = "Blue", Color = Color.DeepSkyBlue },
            new Model { Text = "BurlyWood", Color = Color.BurlyWood }, };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Model> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Model
{
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I had x:DataType="local:ViewModel" in definition of my page. When I removed this it worked.

Comment: Thanks @MilanM. I actually had a tooltip help ask to add the DataType entry to help with Binding Intellisense. Had no idea that was what broke my BindingLayout. For anyone else who finds this, you can also add a DataType entry within the DataTemplate declaration and tell it what type it is. So for Milan's entry, changing the DataTemplat to <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Model"> and then adding an xmlns that defines models would have fixed it as well.

Comment: Adding x:DataType would help in my case, too, but it is a KeyValuePair<,> and that seems not to be supported. So I also had to remove it from the page definition with the result that intellisense stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

To close the loop here ... as @MilanM commented on 10-17-20, he got it to work by removing this from the xaml

```
x:DataType="local:ViewModel"
```

I think that other people are saying that the code runs fine because they never had that line in their xaml.  @MilanM never showed it until his comment.

I removed 2 lines from my xaml and everything then worked.

```
xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:MauiApp1.ViewModels"
x:DataType="viewModel:MainViewModel"
```

NOTE: I set the BindingContext in the codebehind with this:

```
public MainPage(MainViewModel _vm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = _vm;
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I tried run your code and see nothing wrong with it
Apart from some slight typo in your question, I have it as this

```
   public ViewModel()
    {
        Data = new ObservableCollection<Model>
        {
            new Model {Text = "Pink", Color = Color.DeepPink},
            new Model {Text = "Crimson", Color = Color.Crimson},
            new Model {Text = "Aqua", Color = Color.Aqua},
            new Model {Text = "Blue", Color = Color.DeepSkyBlue},
            new Model {Text = "BurlyWood", Color = Color.BurlyWood},
        };
    }
```

, maybe try clean/rebuild solution and run again?

[image]