# MVVM bound data in flyoutpage menu only appears in hot reload

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a flyoutpage in xamarin, I'm trying to populate the menu of the flyout based on login credentials. When I compile and run, I see 3 spots in the menu where my items should be displayed, and if I select one of the spots, the target for that spot does indeed activate and takes me to that page. However, my `<label>` text and `<Image>` source do not show. While the app is running, I can see the label text and image by swapping back and forth in the bind for each field (I've noticed in when toying with `Mode=TwoWay / OneWay`. I get no binding errors or compile issues whatsoever.

***EDIT***
`BaseViewModel` includes the `INotifyPropertyChanged` methods.

the FlyoutMenu.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MBRMobile.Flyout.FlyoutMenu"
             xmlns:flyout="clr-namespace:MBRMobile.Flyout"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MBRMobile.Views" 
             x:DataType="flyout:FlyoutViewModel"
             Title="Flyout">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <flyout:FlyoutViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="MenuView"
                      x:FieldModifier="public"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid Padding="10,10">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Grid.Column="0"
                                       Source="{Binding IconSource}" />
                                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                       Text="{Binding MenuTitle}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>                       
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

the FlyoutViewModel.cs

```
{
    public class FlyoutViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private List<FlyoutMenuItems> menuItems;
        public List<FlyoutMenuItems> MenuItems
        {
            get { return menuItems; }
            set
            {
                menuItems = value;
            }
        }
        
        private string menuTitle;
        public string MenuTitle
        {
            get { return menuTitle; }
            set { SetProperty(ref menuTitle, value); }
        }
        private string iconSource;
        public string IconSource
        {
            get { return iconSource; }
            set { SetProperty(ref iconSource, value); }
        }
        private Type targetType;
        public Type TargetType
        {
            get { return targetType; }
            set { SetProperty(ref targetType, value); }
        }

        public string ApptView { get; set; }
        public string DogView { get; set; }
        public string FosterView { get; set; }

        public async void GetStorage()
        {
            this.ApptView = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("MBRMobileRoles_Appointment_View");
            this.DogView = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("MBRMobileRoles_Dog_View");
            this.FosterView = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("MBRMobileRoles_Foster_View");            
        }

        public FlyoutViewModel()
        {
            GetStorage();

            MenuItems = new List<FlyoutMenuItems>();
            if (bool.Parse(ApptView))
            {
                MenuItems.Add(new FlyoutMenuItems
                {
                    MenuTitle = "Appointments",
                    IconSource = "icon_appointments.png",
                    TargetType = typeof(AppointmentsPage)
                });
            }
            if (bool.Parse(DogView))
            {
                MenuItems.Add(new FlyoutMenuItems
                {
                    MenuTitle = "Dogs",
                    IconSource = "icon_dogs.png",
                    TargetType = typeof(DogsPage)
                });
            }
            if (bool.Parse(FosterView))
            {
                MenuItems.Add(new FlyoutMenuItems
                {
                    MenuTitle = "Fosters",
                    IconSource = "icon_fosters.png",
                    TargetType = typeof(FostersPage)
                });
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

and the FlyoutMenuItems.cs class

```
public class FlyoutMenuItems : BaseViewModel
    {

        public FlyoutMenuItems()
        {
            TargetType = typeof(FlyoutMenuItems);
        }


        public string MenuTitle { get; set; }
        public string IconSource { get; set; }
        public Type TargetType { get; set; }
    }
```

***EDIT 2***
Added FlyoutPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FlyoutPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MBRMobile.Views"  
            xmlns:flyout="clr-namespace:MBRMobile.Flyout" 
            xmlns:view="clr-namespace:MBRMobile.Views" 
            x:DataType="local:HomePage"
            x:Class="MBRMobile.Views.HomePage"
            Title="Home">
    <FlyoutPage.Flyout>
        <flyout:FlyoutMenu x:Name="Flyout" />
    </FlyoutPage.Flyout>
    
    <FlyoutPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <flyout:FlyoutPageDetail />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </FlyoutPage.Detail>
</FlyoutPage>
```

Comment: `BaseViewModel` may implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` but this doesn't happen automatically. You still need to call `OnPropertyChanged("name")` in your property setters.

Comment: @FelixCastor, the ```SetProperty()``` method from BaseViewModel calls ```OnPropertyChanged(propertyName)```. If the property wasn't updating, wouldn't the ```Target``` not update as well and the menu would be blank?

Comment: You try to use the `<label>` text and `<Image>` source in FlyoutMenu.xaml without using Binding, first give the content to see if it is displayed. Can you provide the code of your FlyPage?

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT, Im not sure I follow? The binding is in place for both items you mentioned in FlyoutMenu.xaml. I updated my question with the FlyoutPage.xaml at the bottom as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enough digging and trying, I found out that another use had a similar odd issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64313170/9472341

What was occurring was `x:DataType="flyout:FlyoutViewModel"` in my Flyout.xaml was telling me that my `MenuItems` properties `IconSource` and `MenuTitle` didn't exist, and would stop me from compiling. Not thinking about it, I added those properties into my `FlyoutViewModel.cs`, doing so effectively was nulling-out the values that were being set and added to the ObservableCollection.
Further digging by throwing a `Console.WriteLine(propertyName)` within my `BaseViewModel()` show me that I was getting a call twice the number of expected times for those `MenuTitle` properties.

Comment: Glad that you solved it. You could mark your answer that may help others with same issue.